# right syntax for mysql function

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I'm a beginner in mysql c# programming.
I ran into the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '"pass where username=admin1' at line 1

my "update_user_password" function is the following:

```
public Boolean update_user_password(string user_name, string new_password)
    {
        String uu = "update users set password=\"" + new_password + " where username=" + user_name;
        Boolean error = !execute_cmd_db(uu.ToString());
        return !error;
    }
```

Can anyone please tell me how I can fix this error?

Comment: you could fix it by adding some quotes, but I'm encouraging you to use prepared statements.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use quotes around the values of username and password:

```
String uu = "update users set password'\" + new_password + "' where username='" + user_name+"'";
```